# Independence and Consistence of Formal Systems

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, proof-theory, formal-systems

Let $S$ be a formal system with axioms $A,A_1,\dots,A_n$. The system $S$ is said to be consistent if no contradiction can be proved (i.e. we can’t prove both a formula and its negation). If $S$ is consistent, the axiom $A$ is said to be dependent from $A_1,\dots,A_n$ if $A$ can be proved using only $A_1,\dots,A_n$.

Given these definitions, if $S$ and $S'$ are both consistent, with $S’$ created from $S$ by negating $A$ (i.e. the axioms of $S'$ are $\lnot A,A_1, \dots,A_n$), then obviously $A$ is not dependent from $A_1,\dots,A_n$.

Does the opposite holds? That is can we prove that if $S$ is consistent ad $S’$ is not consistent then $A$ can be derived from $A_1,\dots,A_n$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is positive, at least in first-order classical logic (which is the logic you refer to, I guess), where you have completeness and soundness theorems.

*Completeness* theorem states that if every model of $A_1, \dots, A_n$ is a model of $A$ then $A$ can be derived from $A_1, \dots, A_n$.

*Soundness* theorem is the converse of completeness, it states that if $A$ can be derived from $A_1, \dots, A_n$ then every model of $A_1, \dots, A_n$ is a model of $A$.

If $S' = \{A_1, \dots, A_n, \lnot A\}$ is not consistent then $S'$ is not satisfiable i.e. there is no model satisfying $A_1, \dots, A_n, \lnot A$ (because by soundness theorem, if there were such a model, it would satisfy a contradiction, that is impossible). So, every model of $A_1, \dots, A_n$ cannot be a model of $\lnot A$ and hence it is a model of $A$. Therefore, $A$ is derivable from $A_1, \dots, A_n$ by completeness theorem.

Note that the hypothesis that $S$ is consistent is superfluous.

Comment: So we need to add an essential completeness hypothesis on S?

Comment: @MarkusSteiner - When you talk about a formal system $S$, what do you refer to? I guess it is a set of axioms (in a given language) that you add to a (complete and sound) derivation system for first-order classical logic, such as Hilbert system, natural deduction or sequent calculus. Isn't it?

Comment: @MarkusSteiner Your comment suggests to me that you might be confusing completeness of an axiom system (which means that, for any sentence $A$, either $A$ or $\neg A$ is deducible from those axioms) with the completeness theorem for first-order logic (which says that every semantic consequence of any axiom system is deducible from that axiom system). It is unfortunate that these two different concepts have very similar names, both involving the word "completeness".

Comment: Yes you are right, I misunderstood, anyway now it's clear, thank you for you answer.